# how should i get all posts for particular user role in wordpress through plug-in

Tags: wordpress

i am using wordpress database as a backend for android application and i have 2 custom roles in the application one is management and second is user.and i am using members plugin for content permission in wordpress which allows to add permissions.now from my plugin i want to get all the posts for users which has management role.these request will be come as a REST based URL and return json data.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, your question is not clear to understand!

Comment: have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

create a function to alter the query's where clause:

```
function authors_where_filter( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $ids = get_users(array('role' => 'author' ,'fields' => 'ID'));
        $where .= " AND post_author IN ($ids)";
        return $where;
}
```

and then before you query just hook it ex:

```
add_filter('posts_where','authors_where_filter');
$all_posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1 .....
remove_filter('posts_where');
```

and you should get all posts of author users in a single query, (well two actually one to get the users and the other is to get the posts)

[Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56071/how-to-query-post-by-user-role)